# Why this particular point inverse on bitcoin's elliptic curve looks like it doesn't belong to that elliptic curve?

Tags: python, bitcoin, elliptic-curve

I have this point which belongs to a Secp256k1 curve:

```
P(x,y) = (0xeac136e97ce6bf3e2bceb65d906742f7317b6518c54c64353c43dcc36688c47,
          0x477bc56ad656f92ce7ad2e832ced54eb923ee3ca6b35938da81eb91b926e9075)
```

I have inverse of point P:

```
P(x,-y) = (0xeac136e97ce6bf3e2bceb65d906742f7317b6518c54c64353c43dcc36688c47,
           0xcac32ca278717b5313c1a919437275f5d4aacaa2cdf0fa65c6a1bbff59603a8f)
```

Here are my "tests" in Python

```
x = 0xeac136e97ce6bf3e2bceb65d906742f7317b6518c54c64353c43dcc36688c47

y = 0x477bc56ad656f92ce7ad2e832ced54eb923ee3ca6b35938da81eb91b926e9075

_y = 0xcac32ca278717b5313c1a919437275f5d4aacaa2cdf0fa65c6a1bbff59603a8f

F = 0xfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffefffffc2f
```

checking if Point(x,y) really is on bitcoin's elliptic curve:

```
>>> pow(y, 2, F) ==  ((pow(x, 3) + 7) % F)
True
```

checking if Point(x,-y) really is an inverse mod F of Point(x,y):

```
>>> (y*_y) % F
1
```

checking if Point(x, -y) is on bitcoin's elliptic curve:

```
>>> pow(_y, 2, F) ==  ((pow(x, 3) + 7) % F)
False
```

Could anyone show me what I did wrong? As point inverse on elliptic curve should belong to that curve as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You computation of `-y` is faulty. You calculated the *multiplicative* inverse of `y`. Using your definition of `_y`, you can check that `y *_y % F` evaluates to `1`.

Instead, `-y = F-y` in this context:

```
>>> _y = F-y
>>> hex(_y)
'0xb8843a9529a906d31852d17cd312ab146dc11c3594ca6c7257e146e36d916bba'
>>> pow(_y, 2, F) ==  ((pow(x, 3) + 7) % F)
True
```

Comment: Yeah, cheers for spotting this. I actually took point inverse from mpz_invert method of GMP library, will investigate why it gives me wrong value ( can't give you any points as I'm new on this portal and don't have enough reputation ;) )

Comment: @JohnTamed At first I thought that maybe there was some weird endian type issue, but instead the problem was that the method you used calculated an inverse that you didn't need. See the edit.

Comment: @JohnTamed: `mpz_invert` gives you the wrong value because it's the wrong method.